# Xcode/ Custom Button/ Alignment

Tags: xcode, button, alignment

I am having a weird problem with xcode, I created a button with an image in it, and trying to put center the image in the button.

It is weird that if I click center horizontal in xcode, it always one step close to the left side. If I set it align with the right side, it isnt going to the right end. Anyone have any cue what is wrong with my xcode...

thanks for helping me out, please see the screenshot for your information.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvZ6C.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In size inspector, check a *Content insets* and *Image insets* `right` and `left` if are set to zero